# Android Studio Artifacts

Tags: android-studio

After developing in Eclipse for several years I have switched to Android Studio since two days. Although I have read as much as possible about it I still have one big problem: I can not find the place to add, change, configure or whatever about the so called artifacts.
I have tried several ways from creating a new project from scratch to importing a complete Eclipse projects.
Although the IntelliJ documentation is clear about it, I can not find it.
The project structure in all cases only shows three parts in the structure:
SDK location, Project and app. I have searched them all but no artifacts.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact description is in the IntelliJ IDEA manual that is reached by selecting menu item 'Help, Help Topics' in Android Studio.
However, according to JetBrains Support the Android Studio documentation topics need to be updated and the Artifacts page should not be available in Android Studio. 
See also: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/58563